# How can I Detect external monitor is in mirror or extended by command?

Tags: linux, display, hdmi, xrandr

How can I detect that my external monitor is in mirror mode or extended mode or set in primary. I have done with so many commands like **xrandr** is there its giving me the output where I can say that what is the primary display but looking by any output I cannot figure out that is it in extended mode or in mirror mode can anyone please help me.

Comment: You need to compare the coordinates and offset (will look something like `1280x1024+0+0` to see if there is an overlap (mirror) or not (extended).

Comment: Is not there any command available that will return as "mirror" or "extended". Cause this will create confusion I think

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea. I got a logic from here. After resolution if extended those "0" will change into extended size , in mirror those will be 0 only.